# Does Android 4.4 support CSS page breaks?

Tags: android, css, printing, page-break

We are creating printable documents through the browser and the client wants to move from laptops to tablets.

The only obstacle is printing. I've set up [a test page](http://jsfiddle.net/qu7pX/show/).

I need to know whether `page-break-before: always` will work on Android. (Test #2)

It would also be nice to know whether `@media print` and `@media screen` are respected. (Test #1)

(iPad supports these features, but the implementation has serious flaws. Windows works of course - but Android would be the preference.)

Comment: I reckon that is a feature easier tested than someone with a specific answer. In case you don't have an Android 4.4 device at hand, I suggest you check Genymotion. They provide superb Android emulator with all main API versions.

Comment: Also, please bear in mind that there are many Android Web browser apps for Android, and not all will handle CSS the same.

Comment: @Commons, Good point. In my case, the client will choose the browser I recommend, so I am flexible there.

Comment: That's all the more reason why you will need to do your own testing. You have to choose a browser that you are able to recommend and that will be installable on all of the client's devices. So, for example, saying "the default browser" will not work, unless you are *sure* that all devices will have the same such browser (app and version), which is usually not the case. Instead, you will want to test browsers that are installable (for where they are not pre-installed), like Chrome, Firefox, etc.